# Constructor of class 'Blob' is private and only accessible within the class declaration

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, blob

```
import { Blob } from '@firebase/firestore-types';


@Injectable()
export class ImagehandlerProvider {
  nativepath: any;
  firestore = firebase.storage();
  imagestore: any;

  constructor(public filechooser: FileChooser, public blob: Blob) {
    console.log('Hello ImagehandlerProvider Provider');
  }

  uploadimage() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      this.filechooser.open().then((url)=> {
        (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, (result)=> {
          this.nativepath = result;
          (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.nativepath, (res)=> {
            res.File((resFile)=> {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
              reader.onloadend = (ent: any) => {
               // var imgBlob = new Blob([ent.target.result], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
               var imgBlob = new Blob([ent.target.result], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
                var imgStore = this.firestore.ref(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('profilepic');
                imgStore.put(imgBlob).then((res)=> {
                  alert('Upload successful');
                }).catch((error)=> {
                  alert('Upload failed' + error);
                })
              }
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }

}
```

The code above has a simple problem. I am on the 3rd day learning ionic-angular, I want to implement image upload, and I think by default angular makes all imported classes private. I have searched  online how to Blob is implemented and have sen that it is by instantiating the Blob class, which I did, since the class is made private by default it's not accessible so I have to create a public property in the constructor of this class. In short way, without creating this property I am getting this error:

```
[ts] Constructor of class 'Blob' is private and only accessible within the class declaration.
```

How do I make use of the Blob class

Comment: is your `Blob` class an `interface` having decorator `Injectable()`?

Comment: To be sincere, I don't know. This is my third day running angularjs and all I can see is that the Blob class is imported from firebase as indicated here - ```import { Blob } from '@firebase/firestore-types';```